# How can I protect myself against knockback?

Tags: diablo-iii

I'm currently in the middle of Act III with my monk and spend a lot of my time not hitting the enemy because I'm too busy being knocked into the air by my enemies. They seem to have a very high chance to cause the knockback effect any time they hit me, which is pretty annoying.

What factors affect the knockback chance, and how can I reduce the chance that I get knocked back?

Comment: Have you considered switching your main to [Deadly Reach](http://eu.battle.net/d3/en/class/monk/active/deadly-reach)? Should help with not getting hit...

Answer (score 1):

Sadly, I think the only effective way to protect yourself from knock-back right now is to increase your dodge %, since dodging attacks that knock you back will keep you from getting knocked back.

It's noteworthy that blocking an attack with a shield won't keep you from getting used as a pinball.

Answer (score 0):

Monks have an ability called "Serenity" which does the following:

> You are enveloped in a protective shield that absorbs all incoming
>   damage for 3 seconds and grants immunity to all control imparing
>   effects.

Given that the effect only lasts 3 seconds, it's hard to confirm 100%, but I haven't ever been knocked back when using that skill (my Monk is also in Act III).